# What is `file_store` in the `ci_job_artifacts`?

Tags: gitlab

Where is this field defined and what does it mean? I can't find any information about it.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file_store` field in `ci_job_artifacts` [corresponds to the code in `app/uploaders/object_storage.rb`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/app/uploaders/object_storage.rb#L28),

Currently it only has two values,

```ruby
module Store
  LOCAL = 1
  REMOTE = 2
end
```

This can be used to determine if the artifact exists in a [Object Storage backend](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/object_storage.html), or local storage.